# Misunderstanding of the proof of the Riemann–Roch theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to understand the proof of the Riemann–Roch theorem presented [here](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Talovikova.pdf) (p. 11).

Before I state the question itself, let me give some background material (i.e., a summary of what is going on in my understanding).

> Let $X$ be a Riemann surface, $D$ a divisor on $X$. By $L(D)$ we
>   mean the set of all meromorphic functions $f$ on $X$ such that
>   $(f)+D\ge0$; where $(f)$ is the principal divisor of $f$ and the
>   notation $(f)+D\ge0$ means that all the (integer) coefficients in the divisor
>   $(f)+D$ are nonnegative.
>
> For the divisor $D=\sum_{i=1}^n{m_ia_i}$, we set
>   $V=\{(f_1,\dots,f_n)\}$, where
>   $f_k=\frac{c_{-m_k}}{z^k}+\dots+\frac{c_{-1}}{z}.$ It is a vector
>   space over $\mathbb{C}$ of dimension $\deg(D):=\sum_{i=1}^n m_i$.
>
> Define a map $\Phi: L(D)\rightarrow V$ as follows: to a function
>   $f\in L(D)$ it assigns the $n-$tuple with $i$th element being the principal part of Laurent's expansion of $f$ at the point $a_i$.

I think I don't completely understand the definition of the set $V$ and the map $\Phi$. To get a deeper understanding, I consider the following example.

Let $\mathbb{C}$ be the Riemann surface being considered and let $$D=a_1\cdot   m_1+a_2\cdot m_2+a_3\cdot m_3=0\cdot3+1\cdot 3+2\cdot4$$ be a divisor on $\mathbb{C}$ with $a_i\in\mathbb{C}$ and $m_i\in\mathbb{Z}$. Further, let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a meromorphic function defined by $f(z)=\frac{1}{z(z-1)^2(z-2)^3}$. It is easy to verify that $f\in L(D)$.

Now, if we denote by $V(D)$ what is denoted merely by $V$ in the article ($V$ is constructed from $D$, so I find it reasonable), then $$V(D)=\bigg\{ \bigg(\frac{c_{-3}}{z^3}+\frac{c_{-2}}{z^2}+\frac{c_{-1}}{z},\frac{d_{-3}}{z^3}+\frac{d_{-2}}{z^2}+\frac{d_{-1}}{z}, \frac{e_{-4}}{z^4}+\frac{e_{-3}}{z^3}+\frac{e_{-2}}{z^2}+\frac{e_{-1}}{z}\bigg)\bigg\} $$

However, $$\Phi(f)=\\{\bigg(-\frac{1}{8z},\frac{1}{2(z-1)^2}-\frac{2}{z-1},\frac{1}{2(z-2)^3}-\frac{5}{4(z-2)^2}+\frac{17}{8(z-2)}\bigg)\\}$$

So the question which arises immediately is why $\Phi(f)\in V(D)$? Of course, it is an $n-$tuple, but it contains powers of $z-2$ for example, whereas the definition of $V$ includes only powers of $z$. Moreover, for an arbitrary $g\in L(D)$, why the $k$th element in the n-tuple $\Phi(g)$ will always have the power of $z$ (or $z-\alpha$?) not exceeding $m_{k}$ by absolute value?

Comment: I wouldn't trust REU papers completely — people are usually in a bit of a rush. There are many trusted sources (Forster, Farkas-Kra, Griffiths, Kirwan, Gunning, Arbarello-Cornalba-Griffiths-Harris ...) that will get this right. Anyway I think it's letter to just think of this as a map $L(D) \to \mathbf C^{\deg D}$ where, say, the first $m_1$ coordinates are the Laurent coefficients when you expand at $a_1$ and so on.

Comment: @Hoot: Thanks for references! The reason why I used this article is that the majority of sources (for example, Forster, Farkas-Kra, Arbarello-Cornalba-Griffiths-Harris) use a more advanced language (including cohomology etc.). I'll try to look through Kirwan and Gunning, maybe I will be satisfied with their language.

Comment: Oh I didn't mean... I just mean that if I'm reading Deligne and something seems off then probably the issue is within me. If I'm reading my friend's REU paper then it's 50-50.